# Оптимизировать работу условий через if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как в один if сделать такие проверки если результат всегда один

```
 if (this.percentUse > this.percentAll) {
      return 0;
    }
 if (this.percentUse === 0 || this.percentAll === 0) {
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: у тебя должно выполниться первое условие ИЛИ второе

Comment: Хорошо как это сделать лаконичней ?

Comment: if (this.percentUse > this.percentAll || this.percentUse === 0 || this.percentAll === 0) {
          return 0;
        }

Comment: а что не лаконичного в строчке выше?

Comment: аххах вы издеваетесь. Можно код написать немного лучше, почему это не сделать

Comment: "лучше" у каждого свое. Непонятно, что не так в трех простых условиях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считаю, что тут не надо делать условие в одну строку. Если условия будут добавляться, то и условие будет становится шире и шире, всё больше нечитабельной портянкой.

Вот на что стоило бы потратить силы, так это выделить условия в переменные, которые "говорят" что они делают и почему. И тогда уже эти переменные, если так надо, вставить в усиловие.

Пример:

```
let usagePercentIsExceeded = this.percentUse > this.percentAll;
let percentsDoNotAccrued = this.percentUse === 0 || this.percentAll === 0;

if (usagePercentIsExceeded || percentsDoNotAccrued) 
    return 0;
```

Более того, желательно сделать отдельный метод, также с нужным "говорящим" названием. Потому что почему возвращается 0 - не ясно

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (true) {
  case this.percentUse > this.percentAll:
  case this.percentUse === 0:
  case this.percentAll === 0:
    return 0;
}
```